# probability given poisson dist.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Librarians in busy libraries can re-shelf quite a few books a day. Assume that for each librarian 4 books per day get placed on the wrong shelf on average.  in the first 15 days of March, the librarian placed 48 books on the wrong shelf. what is the probability the librarian will have incorrectly shelved 100 books by the end of March.  I know its a Poisson dist. but I don't know how to set this up and carry it out; I know it's $P(X=100\, \text{given} X>48)$ but I don't know how to carry it out

Comment: Hmmm. P(X=100 given X=48) = 0 because X=100 and X=48 are incompatible, no?

Comment: i updated it for you sorry

Comment: In the first 15 days, did the librarian put _at least_ 48 books on wrong shelves, or _exactly_ 48 books on wrong shelves? From the wording of the problem I would have assumed it was an exact amount (just as the 100 books at the end is an exact amount), in which case we're asking for the probability to put exactly 52 books on wrong shelves in 16 days (March has 31 days), assuming the librarian never gets a day off.

Comment: they put exactly 48 books on the wrong shelf.

Comment: so how would i find the probability of putting 52 books on wrong shelves in 16 days?

Comment: ...Except that X>48 is not involved in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If errors are Poisson distributed, then they must be
independent occurrences. Hence the Comment by @DavidK,
simplifies the problem to asking for $P(X = 52),$
where $X \sim Pois(\lambda)$ and $\lambda$ is the error
rate for 16 days.

The mistake rate is 4 *per day,* and thus the error rate is $\lambda = 4(16) = 64$
for the remaining period of *16 days.* (In my experience, a major source of error
in working problems with the Poisson distribution is failure
to adjust the error rate exactly to match the problem at hand.)

The probability is computed as 
$P(X = 52) = e^{-\lambda}\lambda^52/52!.$

In R this is could be done by using `dpois` (the Poisson PDF)
or by direct computation.

```
 dpois(52, 64)
 ## 0.01659065
 exp(-64)*(64)^52/factorial(52)
 ## 0.01659065
```

However, I'm wondering if the problem might have meant
"... incorrectly shelved *at least* 100 books by the end of March."
In that case, you'd want $P(X \ge 52) = 1 - P(X \le 51):$

```
 1 - ppois(51, 64)
 ## 0.9447987
```

The question arises whether you were expected to use the normal
approximation to the Poisson. The 'best fitting' normal distribution
to $Pois(64)$ is $Norm(\mu = 64, \sigma = 8)$. Using the
continuity correction I get a normal approximation of
$P(X \ge 51.5)$ to be about 94%.

Note: To get a reasonable normal approximation for $P(X = 52)$,
you should begin with $P(51.5 < X < 52.5).$

Here is a plot of some of the probabilities in the distribution
$Pois(64)$ along with the approximating normal density curve.
[image]

*Addendum:* One might wonder whether making 48 mistakes in the initial 15 days
is consistent with an error rate of 4 per day. One 95% confidence
interval for $\lambda$ (15-day rate) would be $X + 2 \pm 1.96\sqrt{X + 1}$
or $(36.28, 63.72)$. For the per day
error rate, this is $(2.42, 4.25)$, which includes $\lambda =4$,
as originally stated. So, in this respect, the librarian
behaved according to the model for the first half of the month.